# stacked bar chart from grouped object

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I get the expected count of following group-by query. But when I add `.plot.bar()` method, I get bar chart for each record.
How do I get stacked bar chart?

```
df.groupby(['department', 'status'])['c_name'].count()

department                                                status  
Agriculture                                               Accepted      3
                                                          Pending       2
                                                          Rejected     13
Department of Education and Training                  Accepted    290
                                                          Rejected     65
Higher Education                                  Accepted    424
                                                          Pending      24
                                                          Rejected     92
Medical Education and Research                    Accepted     34
                                                          Pending       3
                                                          Rejected      1
```

This will create a bar chart but not the stacked one.

```
.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

For each department there should be 3 colors (for Accepted, Pending and Rejected)

---

Update:

I managed using pivot.

```
gdf=df.groupby(['department', 'status'])['c_name'].count().reset_index()
gdf.pivot(index='department', columns='status').plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

But is it possible to improve the chart quality?

Comment: The stacking needs to be done column wise, one column for each stack. In this case 3 columns `Accepted`, `Pending`, `Rejected`.

Comment: Thanks for providing additional information to your post by using the [edit] functionality. But please [don't pollute your post with `EDIT:` or `UPDATE:` sections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127639/when-is-edit-update-appropriate-in-a-post). For future readers, posts need to be standalone, without any history. These sites are not forums, but intend to be libraries of canonical, high-quality, questions and answers. Future readers are not helped by seeing all kind of history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close, need [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df.groupby(['department','status'])['c_name'].count().unstack().plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Thanks. The default chart does not look professional. Is it possible to have a bigger and better chart?

Comment: @shantanuo - For bigger size of plots is possible use `.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, figsize=(8,6))`. What think `better graph` ?